# Text change on Hover in Stateless Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of icons. On hover, I'm trying to get the corresponding text to display. Is there a way to do this with a stateless component?

```
const Socialbar = (props) => {
   let spanText;

   function socialName(sName) {
    spanText = sName;
   }

   return (
     <div>
      <i><a onMouseEnter={socialName('Instagram')} onMouseExit={socialName('')} href=""><FontAwesomeIcon="faInstagram" /></a></i>
      <h2>{spanText}</h2>
     </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Technically, functional components are no longer stateless..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Socialbar = (props) => {
   const [spanText, setSpanText] = useState('');

   function socialName(sName) {
    if (sName !== spanText) {
        setSpanText(sName);
    }
   }

   return (
     <div>
      <i><a onMouseEnter={() => socialName('Instagram')} onMouseLeave={() => socialName('')} href=""><FontAwesomeIcon="faInstagram" /></a></i>
      <h2>{spanText}</h2>
     </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an "Too many rerenders" error. Is it because the function is being called over and over again onMouseExit?

Comment: The social name will be static? like Instagram

Comment: There will be multiple icons with different social media icons that I want the h2 to display onMouseEnter.

Comment: Try to put an if inside function socialName to compare the name and proceed just if is diferent

Comment: Unfortuantely, still getting the error. If I remove the onMouseExit tag all together, it will render the page, but will not display the spanText.